# Angularjs ng-class multiple class

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to apply the ng class in angularjs with such a condition that if the 
value of the json is 1 to achieve the color of green, 2 would be red, 0 will be white. But for some reason I am not able to get the result. I also have a jsfiddle if you want to look the code more clearly.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/0xsv2aq3/42/
```

Any help will really be appreciate it. Thank you

```
    <html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.schedule =

{
  "days": [
    {
      "day": "2018-12-09T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "3rd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2018-12-16T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Keys 2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "3rd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "2nd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "3rd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2018-12-23T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "2nd"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2018-12-30T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Keys 2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "2nd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2019-01-06T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "3rd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2019-01-13T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Keys 2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "3rd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "2nd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2019-01-20T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Keys 2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "2nd"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "2019-01-27T00:00:00",
      "entries": [
        {
          "name": "Adam D",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "EG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Chris S",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Debbie J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Dennis S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Lead"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jamie W",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Jen C",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Joe T",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Drums"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Karen B",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Kristene B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "Melody"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Lisa R",
          "value": 0,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Mike B",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "AG"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Nancy S",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Paul N",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Scott J",
          "value": 2,
          "parts": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Trisha S",
          "value": 1,
          "parts": [
            "2nd"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


}
</script>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table class="table" border=1>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th ng-repeat=" x in schedule.days" scope="col">{{x.day}}</th>





            </tr>
          </thead>
<style>
.red{background-color: red;}
.white{background-color: white;}
.green{background-color: green;}
</style>

          <tbody>
            <tr  ng-class="{'red': day.entries[$parent.$index].value === 1, 'green': day.entries[$parent.$index].value === 2, 'white': day.entries[$parent.$index].value === 0}"  ng-repeat="day1 in schedule.days[0].entries" scope="row">
               <td>{{day1.name}}</td>
              <td ng-repeat="day in schedule.days">{{day.entries[$parent.$index].parts[0]}}>{{day.entries[$parent.$index].value}}</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>



















  <!-- <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table class="table" border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th ng-repeat=" x in schedule.days" scope="col">{{x.day}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat=" item in schedule.days" scope="row">
            <td ng-repeat="y in item.entries">{{y.value}}</td>

          <td ng-repeat=" itm in item.parts">{{itm}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a custom filter for applying class to td

```
myApp.filter('color',function(){
return function(status){
console.log(status);
    switch(status){
            case 0:
            return 'white';
            break;
        case 1:
            return 'red';
            break;
        case 2:
            return 'green';
            break;

    }
}
});
```

Add the filter in td tag

```
<td class="{{day.entries[$parent.$index].value | color}}" ng-repeat="day in schedule.days">{{day.entries[$parent.$index].parts[0]}}>{{day.entries[$parent.$index].value}}</td>
```

Comment: the case goes with id?

Comment: what Id, i don't get you ?

Comment: I pratically learn something new that is amazing I did not you can use filter this is amazing. I am giving you best answer amazing

Comment: Quick question is it possible to match the string in filter to ?  for instance if produce.name == danny. You apply green color using filter ?  just curious this  is totally amazing easy to maintain the code thank you

Comment: thank danny...
you can check condition in filter as if(produce.name == "danny") and return the green class.
you can also form the html string itself in filter  and bind to tag. use ng-bind-html in tag.

Comment: I am still preety new can you help me with creating a small snippet with that filter if you can. If no not an issue i can work on my end this was the best answer for sure .thank you

Comment: Check this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0xsv2aq3/44/
Added new Filter with $sce so you can form the html string in filter Itself and can bind to View.

Comment: thank you so much this is wayy too perfect thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I was apply the style to the tr tag rather than td.

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/omelsoft/xL35psco/5/'
```

This solved my problem